# Holder estimates for the gradient of the solutions to the linear divergence form elliptic equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Now I'm considering the Drichlet problem
\begin{align}
(a_{ij}(x)u_{x_i})_{x_j}+b_i(x)u_{x_i}+c(x)u &= f(x),\quad x\text{ in }\Omega \\
u(x) &= g(x),\quad x\text{ on } \partial \Omega.\tag{1}
\end{align}
I need some results about the gradient holder estimates of the weak solution under the appropriate smoothness assumption on the coefficients and data,but $a_{ij}$ must be in $C^{\alpha}(\bar\Omega)$ only. Such as the form as follows

$$||Du||_{C^{\alpha}(\bar\Omega)}\leq C(\text{depends on what?})(||u||_{C(\bar\Omega)}+||g||_{X}+||f||_Y).\tag{2}$$

Any answer and reference is appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you consulted the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger?

Comment: @5pm: In my memory，there is only the result for quasilinear divergence type not linear divergence type in the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger. In addition we only assume $a_{ij}\in C^{\alpha}$ not $a_{ij}\in C^{1,\alpha}$, so we can't put $(1)_1$ into non-divergence type. I have known the solvability of non-divergence form linear elliptic equations in holder space.I have modified my post.

Comment: @5pm：I just look up the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger，but I didn't find anything I need.（Because that I'm not very familiar with this book and that my understanding of the elliptic theory of PDE is weak.）Can you locate the knowledge I need in the book? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Silly me,I find them！:)

Comment: If you found what you wanted, please post an answer indicating which chapter/sections it was in. So that other people will know, should they have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the suggestion of 5pm，I find the result in chapter 8,section 8.11 of the book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by Gilbarg and Trudinger.